FastAPI Azure Opentelemetry logger does not map LogLevels correctly
Logs of my FastAPI app are currently written into AppServiceConsoleLogs table in Log Analytics, Azure. I initialize my loggers with (where LOGGING_CONFIG is just the logging config as Class):
class ApiLoggerConfig(BaseModel):
    """Logging configuration to be set for all APIs."""

    formatters: dict = {
        "uvicorn": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s  %(name)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": DATEFMT,
        },
        "access": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
            "fmt": '%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s  %(name)s: %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',
            "datefmt": DATEFMT,
        },
    }

    handlers: dict = {
        "uvicorn": {
            "formatter": "uvicorn",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr",
        },
        "access": {
            "formatter": "access",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
    }

    loggers: dict = {
        "uvicorn": {"handlers": ["uvicorn"], "level": LOG_LEVEL, "propagate": False},
        "uvicorn.error": {"level": LOG_LEVEL},
        "uvicorn.access": {
            "handlers": ["access"],
            "level": LOG_LEVEL,
            "propagate": False,
        },
    }
    def add_logger(
        self,
        name: str,
        handler: str = "default",
        propagate: bool = False,
    ):

        self.loggers[name] = {
            "handlers": [handler],
            "level": self.LOG_LEVEL,
            "propagate": propagate,
        }


def _setup_logging(app: FastAPI):
    LOGGING_CONFIG = ApiLoggerConfig()
    # Load Azure logging config for cloud setup only
    if os.getenv("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"):
        from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
        from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor

        # set metrics extractor to root
        configure_azure_monitor()
        FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)
    LOGGING_CONFIG.add_logger(__name__)
    dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)


app = FastAPI()

logger = _setup_logging(app)

@app.get("/", response_model=HealthResponse)
async def health() -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Simple heath check endpoint.

    Returns:
        The response follows the provided HealthResponse schema.
    """
    logger.info("I am healthy")
    return {"message": "API running."}


However, INFO logs get associated with the LogLevel ERROR ( especially for all logs of the __name__ logger). The setup works locally without any issues.

What am I doing wrong?

The FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app) setup is useful for collecting OpenTelemetry traces. However, it does not directly manage logging output.

Yes, but initializing configure_azure_monitor () does, no? How can I change this then? I "followed" this example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry/samples/logging/basic.py

configure_azure_monitor() function from the azure-monitor-opentelemetry package simplifies the process of setting up telemetry collection for Azure Monitor, including logging telemetry.

In the above case, configure_azure_monitor() initializes logging telemetry, but the example you provided demonstrates manual control over which loggers are tracked by specifying logger_name when calling configure_azure_monitor().

Ok, so this has nothing to do with the logs that are being send? How can I then change the mismatch between the loglevels?

I can see that the configure_azure_monitor() initializes the AzureMonitorLogExporter class which initializes the handler for the export.. but there I am kind of stuck why it is not mapped correctly in my table.

Specifying logger_name limits the telemetry to the specified logger and its child loggers. If not, it tracks all loggers in the application by default.

Add an explicit AzureMonitorTraceExporter and integrates it with Open Telemetry’s BatchSpanProcessor for fine-grained control.

Here I introduce a custom TRACE log level (severity level 5) for more granular log tracking and also Implemented a CustomProcessor to check that TRACE logs are labeled with SeverityLevel=Information in Application Insights.


Here I have aligned logging setup with the example you provided.
import os
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig
from typing import Dict

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

# Azure Monitor and OpenTelemetry imports
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.logging import LoggingInstrumentor
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorTraceExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource

# Constants
DATEFMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
LOG_LEVEL = "TRACE"  # Custom TRACE level
INSTRUMENTATION_KEY = "*****************************"

# Define TRACE log level
TRACE_LEVEL = 5
logging.addLevelName(TRACE_LEVEL, "TRACE")


def trace(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.isEnabledFor(TRACE_LEVEL):
        self._log(TRACE_LEVEL, message, args, **kwargs)


logging.Logger.trace = trace


class HealthResponse(BaseModel):
    """Schema for health check response."""
    message: str


class ApiLoggerConfig(BaseModel):
    """Logging configuration for the application."""

    formatters: dict = {
        "default": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s  %(name)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": DATEFMT,
        },
    }

    handlers: dict = {
        "default": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",  # Send logs to stdout
        },
    }

    loggers: dict = {
        "uvicorn": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": LOG_LEVEL, "propagate": False},
        "uvicorn.error": {"level": LOG_LEVEL},
        "uvicorn.access": {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": LOG_LEVEL,
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "__main__": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": LOG_LEVEL, "propagate": False},
    }

    root: dict = {
        "handlers": ["default"],
        "level": LOG_LEVEL,
    }


def _setup_logging(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialize logging with TRACE support
    LOGGING_CONFIG = ApiLoggerConfig()
    dictConfig(
        {
            "version": 1,
            "formatters": LOGGING_CONFIG.formatters,
            "handlers": LOGGING_CONFIG.handlers,
            "loggers": LOGGING_CONFIG.loggers,
            "root": LOGGING_CONFIG.root,
        }
    )

    # Configure Azure Monitor and OpenTelemetry
    if INSTRUMENTATION_KEY:
        os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] = (
            f"InstrumentationKey={INSTRUMENTATION_KEY}"
        )
        configure_azure_monitor(logging_level=TRACE_LEVEL)  # Include TRACE
        FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)

        # Add custom trace exporter
        exporter = AzureMonitorTraceExporter(
            connection_string=os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
        )

        class CustomProcessor:
            def on_end(self, span):
                # Modify span attributes to ensure TRACE is mapped correctly
                if span.name == "TRACE":
                    span.attributes["severity_level"] = "Information"

        # Set up the OpenTelemetry provider
        resource = Resource.create(attributes={"service.name": "FastAPI App"})
        provider = TracerProvider(resource=resource)
        processor = BatchSpanProcessor(exporter)
        provider.add_span_processor(processor)
        provider.add_span_processor(CustomProcessor())  # Add custom processor
        from opentelemetry import trace

        trace.set_tracer_provider(provider)

    return logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Initialize FastAPI app
app = FastAPI()
logger = _setup_logging(app)


@app.get("/", response_model=HealthResponse)
async def health() -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Health check endpoint."""
    logger.trace("TRACE log: Health check endpoint called.")
    logger.info("INFO log: Health check successful.")
    return {"message": "API running."}


# For local testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)



The above code combines configure_azure_monitor with explicit OpenTelemetry SDK configurations, including a TracerProvider and span processors.

Check Azure Monitor Logs to confirm the log level alignment.


Application Insights:



thanks for the input but as I said, I do not want to have transactional traces but solely exporting the logs to app insights or log analytis workspace

You can streamline the setup by configuring the log handler, AzureLogHandler sends logs to Application Insights. It Skips other parts like telemetry clients or tracing.
